# xcode source control repository for multiple projects

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I've created several Xcode projects that share various subsets of modules. I've confused myself trying to make sure I'm using the correct version (usually looking for the most mature version) of specific modules in the various projects. Source Control seems like the logical solution so I've started using it. 
1) Can I connect multiple Xcode projects to one central/master repository? (Various stack overflow posts imply this can be done but I can't seem to get Xcode Source Control to do it.)
2) Can I then #include a different subset of modules from that master repository into each different project? (I understand how to selectively committee changes.)
3) Am I envisioning a reasonable approach for my scenario or do you have a better suggestion?

I really don't want to become a Source Control expert: I'm frustrated to get back to the programming task at hand.

Thanks!
      Nick

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing VCS's with Dependencies?

Comment: Harmelodic:

Since I'm not sure I understand your question so I guess my answer must be that I am, in fact, confused. I suppose by "VCS" you mean "version control system", right? And I suppose by "Dependencies" you mean the equivalent of #includes in a C project? I'm looking for a fairly simple way to manage both across multiple Xcode Projects. 

Xcode Project P1 #includes Functions A and B . 

A second Xcode Project P2 consists of B and C. How do I best pull in the most mature version of B into P2? If I change B how do I best get it back into P1?

Comment: You are correct in your suppositions.

Dependencies are managed by a dependency manager. So for Xcode/Cocoa Projects your could use CocoaPods or Carthage.

Source Control is managed by a VCS such as Git or SVN.

Assuming those 2 projects are modules of 1 application, you would need a dependency manager to manage your dependencies, and a VCS such as Git to manage your source code.

If the projects are 2 seperate applications, you'll need a dependency manager for each project and a VCS enabled for each project (unless you use Git submodules).

Answer (score 0):

Barring any better ideas I have established a "master" repository in a new Xcode project. As I create new subprojects i start them as branches off the master. As I create new functions in the branches I periodically *selectively* merge them into the master. Similarly when I fix a bug in an existing branch/function I *selectively* merge it back into the master. I don't delete the separate branches (unless I really never want to use one again). If I delete a function from a particular branch I do not accept that change when I merge back to the master. That way the master should stay all-inclusive. If I re-open a branch I haven't used in a while, my plan is to "merge from" the master (*very* selectively) to be sure I have updated that old branch for subsequent bug fixes. (I haven't tried all these, but so far so good.)